# Are we having fun yet?

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is from a TV show.

P. J. is a teen. He's taken his newborn sister to the park. He leaves his sister alone in the stroller, while he is playing on a rocking bird for little kids.

Later, when he is finished, he comes back, gets down by the stroller, and asks his sister,

> Hey there, Charlie, are we having fun yet?

Does he mean "are *you* having fun yet"?

Yet is used in present perfect, right? So, isn't it

> "have we had fun yet "?

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/are+we+having+fun+yet https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Are%20we%20having%20fun%20yet%3F

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in the comments, [are we having fun yet](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/are+we+having+fun+yet) is an idiom, however it doesn't sound that unusual.

- "You" is sometimes replaced by "we", to sound patronizing, when an adult speaks to a small child or a pet, perhaps even in a funny voice.  "Are we hungry?" "Are we ok?" "How are we doing?"
- While "yet" might typically be used in the present perfect, the present tense isn't impossible.  For example: "Are we there? Are we there yet?"  In this case, it seems to indicate impatience, and the probable expectation of  a negative answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/we) lists one definition of "we" as "you":

> used as the subject of a verb to mean "you", especially when talking to a child or someone who is ill:
>
> - We don't want to be late for school, do we?
> - "How are we this morning, Mrs Flanagan?" said the doctor.

To add to that definition, it is a way of generalising but without including yourself in the specific example. Using the first example above, "*we don't want to be late*" - in some contexts, that could include both yourself and the other person, if you were both due to be somewhere. When a parent says this to a child about school, the parent isn't themselves included (they are not personally due to be at school) but the parent is teaching the child a broader life lesson, that lateness is not good, and in that broader sense they are including themselves.